# can xpath be used to search links from website?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am searching for functions like to find if the link exist in the webpage. and if the link exist than print something link "link found!".

example: ( I want to find XPATH "123")

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath ("123"));
if (the xpath found the "123"){ 
   System.out.printIn ("link found") 
} else {
   System.out.printIn ("missing link..")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Selenium Webdriver`?

From the [API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29):

> WebElement findElement(By by)
>
> Find the first WebElement using the
>   given method. This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in
>   force at the time of execution. The findElement(..) invocation will
>   return a matching row, or try again repeatedly until the configured
>   timeout is reached. findElement should not be used to look for
>   non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length
>   response instead.

So your code will probably look something like this:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("123"));
if (allElements == null || allElements.size() == 0) {
    System.out.printIn ("missing link..")
} else {
    System.out.printIn ("link found")
}
```

Comment: yes i am using selenium webdriver.. 

thanks for your solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

Find link by "href" attribute? `'//a[@href="http://www.example.com/somepage"]'`

Find link by text of link? `'//a[normalize-space(.)="Some text link"]'`

Comment: something like that
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]/label"));